# Name 'self' not defined in class?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, self

I'm attempting to filter a queryset by owner, but using `self.request.user` results in a `NameError` for some reason.

```
class PackageListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView, Self):
    model = Package
    user = self.request.user
    queryset = Package.objects.filter(owner=user).order_by('-received_date')
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: capitalize the s in self ---> Self.request.user

Comment: Your parameter is named `Self` not `self` (notice the uppercase). Most programming languages (including Python) are case sensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `queryset` is defined when the class is loaded. You can't access `self.request.user` at this point. Override the `get_queryset` instead.

```
class PackageListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Package

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Package.objects.filter(owner=user).order_by('-received_date')
```

Note I have removed `Self` from the `class PackageListView` line -- it looked like a mistake.

Comment: Thanks. Started working w/ dad on his project and we nearly tore our hair out on this issue.